# how to show two object in an control how i can put each object in separeate column

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
_objbefor = Convertor.XmlDesrialize.XmlDesrializer.DesrializeAnyObject(_XmlObjBefor,  _ObjectType);
        _objAfter = Convertor.XmlDesrialize.XmlDesrializer.DesrializeAnyObject(_XmlObjAfter, _ObjectType);
        //exteract properties of loged object
        PropertyInfo[] _PropertyInfo = _ObjectType.GetProperties();
        List<string> _ObjBeforTostring = new List<string>();
        //_ObjBeforTostring.Add("");
        _ObjBeforTostring.Add("*************Befor Object**********");
        _ObjBeforTostring.Add("");
        foreach (PropertyInfo pf in _PropertyInfo)
        {
            if (_objbefor != null)
            {
                string _str = pf.GetValue(_objbefor, null).ToString();
                _ObjBeforTostring.Add(pf.Name.ToString() + "  ::  ( " + _str + " )");
                _ObjBeforTostring.Add("==============================");
            }


        }
        _ObjBeforTostring.Add("");
        _ObjBeforTostring.Add("*************After Object**********");
        _ObjBeforTostring.Add("");
        foreach (PropertyInfo pf in _PropertyInfo)
        {

            if (_objAfter != null)
            {
                string _str = pf.GetValue(_objAfter, null).ToString();
                _ObjBeforTostring.Add(pf.Name.ToString() + "  ::  ( " + _str+" )");
                _ObjBeforTostring.Add("==============================");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it Christmas today or what?

Comment: hello i have two object i did in run time with reflection get value of entire properties of my objects and add thies to lis<string>

Answer (score 0):

I would do binary serialization:

```
public byte[] Serialize(object myObject)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, myObject);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] result = stream.ToArray();
        stream.Close();
        return result;
}
```